# What is the IF THEN formula for determining different pay levels. Produce 25 to 30 hours, eceive $1.50 per hour increase

Tags: if-statement, excel-formula, formula

I have a pay system that increases the bonus production as more hours are produced by the ASE technician. I would like to have one formula where I am able to enter one number for data entry, but I would have 5 different levels of pay increase. I have my spreadsheet set up as following. However, the formula I created is incorrect:

```
if(b9>=45,b9*o9,if(b9>=40,b9*n9,if(b9>=35,b9*m9,if(b9>=30,b9*l9,if(b9>=25,b9*k9)))))
```

No results as of yet.

Comment: It appears the value in cell b9 is less than 25, in which case the formula you have would not produce any result.  Try changing to `if(b9>=45,b9*o9,if(b9>=40,b9*n9,if(b9>=35,b9*m9,if(b9>=30,b9*l9,if(b9>=25,b9*k9,b9)))))` to at least have a default value (which is the same value as in b9, I assume that would be no bonus).

Comment: Correct. I did copy and paste and this formula did not calculate. Other minor change?

Answer (score 1):

There are several options on how to achieve this without using nested IF functions.  The solutions I am presenting are with the assumption negative hours do not exist.  I came up with 6 different options, based off different ways of looking up the hours worked in a table and returning the corresponding bonus.

## Option 1 - VLOOKUP

Build your table of bonus with the hours where the bonus kicks in as the left column and what the bonus rate is in the second column.  In the example below, it was placed in K13:L17.  VLOOKUP takes the form of:

```
VLOOKUP(Value to look for, table/range to look in, column to pull the result from, match type)
```

So based on your formula, the value you want to look for is B9.  Based on the table in K13:L17, the formula would look like:

```
=VLOOKUP(B9,$K$13:$L$17,2,1)
```

When testing with values greater than 45 it will keep returning the value in cell L17.  If you have hours less than 25 it will throw an error as it could not find the minimum value in the table.  There are a couple of ways to deal with this.

For this options I will use IFERROR function.  IFERROR will return the result of the function in it if there is not error, but will supply an alternate result if there is an error.  Since there is no bonus for less than 25 hours, the alternate result would be 1 so that when the hours are multiplied by 1 there is no change.  The formula then becomes:

```
=B9*IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B9,$K$13:$L$17,2,1),1)
```

## Option 2 - HLOOKUP

This option is basically the same as option 1 except the look up table is horizontal instead of vertical.  It looks for the same information in the same order.  instead of column to look in, it will be row to look in.

For this option I chose to use an alternate way of dealing with hours less than 25.  Notice in the example below the horizontal table is in J8:O9.  The thing to note is this table starts with a 0 hours options.  Meaning that when performing the HLOOKUP, all hours less than 25 and greater than or equal to 0 will result in cell J9 being returned which would have a value of 1.  Same job as IFERROR.  Big different is IFERROR can handle negative hours (which should not happen) and 0 in the lookup does not.  This method can also be used for VLOOKUP.

NOTE: Either method can be used for hours less than 25 for any of the options

## Option 3 - CHOOSE

Similar to the methodology that Scott Holtzman used, develop a formula that will results in an integer being determine from 1 to 6 to cover all the possible bonus results (6 because no bonus is a result not cover in your original question).

All you breakpoints for bonuses are a multiple of 5.  If you divide all all the breakpoints by 5 you will wind up with the sequence:

```
5, 6, 7, 8, 9
```

This is a good starting point,  however you want to bring the sequence down to 1-5 range.  This is a pretty simple shift achieved by subtracting 4.  So we have the building blocks of a formula.  The thing is we need to apply this to the value in B9 which may not be a nice number divisible evenly by 5.  You will only want to deal with the integer.  With that in mind the formula would become:

```
=INT(B9/5)-4

or

ROUNDOWN(B9/5,0)-4
```

I prefer fewer characters (would not know it from the length of this answer) so I stuck with the INT version.  Now to deal with time in B9 in greater than or equal to 50 you want to cap your result at no more than 5.  This can be achieved using the MIN function and your formula becomes:

```
=MIN(5,INT(B9/5)-4)
```

And to deal with time less than 25 hours, I will cap in the other direction at 0 using the MAX function and your formula now looks like:

```
=MAX(0,MIN(5,INT(B9/5)-4))
```

So now you have a sequence that runs:

```
0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
```

We now have a sequential integer for the 6 possible bonus categories.  We can use the CHOOSE function which will return the nth option is a list starting from 1.  So we need to shift the series by adding one.  The resulting choose formula based on results from your nested IF function would be:

```
=B9*CHOOSE(MAX(0,MIN(5,INT(B9/5-4)))+1,1,$K$9,$L$9,$M$9,$N$9,$O$9)
```

Note: This option wont work if you cannot break your ranges into sequential integers somehow.

## Option 4 - INDEX

INDEX function is interesting as it actually returns a cell address instead of a value from a cell directly.  As an aside, this means you can specify a range by doing something like `INDEX(...):INDEX(...)`.  INDEX basically looks up the position of cell in a range based on sequence number for a 1D range like a column or row.  For a 2D range, INDEX will look up a cell address based on row and column position in the range.  For a 2D range, if you supply 0 for column or row it will return the entire column/row.  INDEX take the following form:

```
1D range
INDEX(Range to look in, Row/Col within the range)

2D range
INDEX(Range to look in, Row within the range, column within the range)
```

Note that if the selected range start in row 1/column A for a 1 D range or A1 for a 2D range, then the worksheet column/row number will match.

For this example the selected range will be the horizontal reference J9:O9.  It could have just as easily been the vertical range in K13:K17.  These are both 1D ranges so the position in the range is determined the same way.  Use the formula from option 3 to generate positions 1 to 6.  This results in the formula:

```
=B9*INDEX($J$9:$O$9,MAX(0,MIN(5,INT(B9/5)-4))+1)
```

Note: This option wont work if you cannot break your ranges into sequential integers somehow.

## Option 5 - INDEX/MATCH

INDEX/MATCH is the preferred method on this site over VLOOKUP/HLOOKUP as it is more versatile in terms of data layout.  Option 4 explains how INDEX works.  That just leaves how to use MATCH.  MATCH will be used to find the ROW/COLUMN where B9 is approximately located.  Similar to the other look ups, it return the last row/column that B9 was equal to or greater than.  MATCH takes the form of:

```
MATCH(value to look for, where to look, match type)
```

For our case we will embed MATCH into the INDEX function and get:

```
=B9*INDEX($J$9:$O$9,MATCH(B9,$J$8:$O$8,1))
```

## Option 6 - LOOKUP

LOOKUP is similar to VLOOKUP/HLOOKUP except that the search range and the result range do not have to be adjacent.  Makes it more like the INDEX/MATCH combination.  I also noted that while the expected inputs are similar to VLOOKUP/HLOOKUP, there is actually not an option for look up type.  LOOKUP take the form of:

```
LOOKUP(what to look for, range to look in, range to return result from)
```

Based on that, and again using the horizontal table J8:O9, the formula becomes:

```
=B9*LOOKUP(B9,$J$8:$O$8,$J$9:$O$9)
```

[image: POC]

NOTE:  In order for matching and look up to work properly, the look up range needs to be sorted in ascending order (smallest to largest).  If you are doing a reverse match then they need to be sorted in descending order.

Comment: Ed. The following of your formula works to a T. =B9*CHOOSE(MAX(0,MIN(5,INT(B9/5-4)))+1,1,$L$9,$M$9,$N$9,$O$9,$P$9)  The only exception is 0-24.99 hours produced. Could I set up a column with a $0.00 value? If so, how would your above formula be calculate with cell K9 value of $0.00?

Comment: the 0-24 hour entries should produce a value of 1, if you want it to be a value of 0 instead, change the 1 before L9 to 0, or to a reference cell which has 0 in it.

Comment: Conversely for the other options doing look ups in tables, change the cell with 1 in it to 0.  in the image above, change J9 to 0.  For the IFERROR method, change the last 1 before the final bracket to 0.

Comment: Forward Ed, you are a genius. Thank you so much for determining this problem of mine. I realize you think it may be simple. But this is not in my wheelhouse. I know what my goal is. However, I did not know the exact formula on how to attain. Thanks again. God bless you.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this easier to manage formula:

```
=B9*OFFSET(K9,0,MIN(4,ROUNDDOWN((B9-25)/5,0)))
```

[image]

Comment: How does that work with hours less than 25 in B9.  ie B9=10?

Comment: @ForwardEd It does not. Nor did the original formula posted by the user handle that case. But it could easily be adjusted to handle that case if needed.

Comment: Scott, the answer is no bonus with less than 25 hours of production. They have a regular hourly rate of $15.